# Reverse engineering on my thesis.pdf

Tags: pdf

I wrote my [thesis](https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/thesis.pdf), which I have uploaded (fortunately) in my pseudo-site. I *had* the source locally. There are some people that decided to work on my project, in order to make it better. As a result, they found typos. I aslo did find some. However, I lost the source of the thesis!

Can I do something about it, from having only the .pdf? Or should I [lie down](https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e6522cfc6dcd3c2b7b77a9d61627b682/dwocyve/3Tin7q81b/tumblr_static_lie-down-try-not-to-cry-cry-a-lot.jpg)?

Comment: you may possibly be able to extract the basic text from the pdf, but the markup is not there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle with my knowledge now I will get nothing, so I am interested.

Comment: there are several utilities for extracting text from pdf, eg I have `pdftotext` installed from the main cygwin repository, seems to be part of the poppler suite

Comment: but really have you really typed an entire thesis without a single backup? no copy, or usb stick or email to yourself or anything?

Comment: A lesson to be learned @DavidCarlisle! The duplicate does not seem to promise a good solution to this, but it's something. Thanks.